# Can't resolve './locale' using react-moment Gatsby

Tags: momentjs, gatsby

Already installed `moment` and `react-moment` and imported in my jsx component like below

```
import React from 'react'
import Moment from 'react-moment'

<Moment format="MMMM D, YYYY">{post.post_date}</Moment>
```

Got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale'`

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to `moment 2.24.0` fixed the issue.

```
yarn add moment@2.24.0
```